# Is there a way to make the Swift compiler ignore errors?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, compilation

I would like to ignore errors when compiling my Swift code. For example, you are writing a class that is not yet used in your application and have errors in it, or if the compiler is just being dumb with all those safety measures, can you compile it anyway? Can you **make** the compiler compile it, even though it is a little bit hack-ish?

Or in other words, how can I make errors be treated as warnings?

Comment: Errors during compilation are unrecoverable problems with your program — unlike warnings, errors indicate that the compiler *wouldn’t* be able to continue compiling because the resulting program wouldn’t make sense. Can you give a specific example of something you’re trying to do?

Comment: For example, why can't you have a `let` constant that is not initialized on `super.init` call? That's quite silly. It is not used in the superclass **by the definition of the superclass**. And anyway, I don't care if does make sense or not. I do **not** ask compiler if it would make sense. I want it **compiled**, not questioned for making sense.

Comment: @Nullcaller That error is actually justified. `super.init`, once finished initializing all of its properties, is well within its rights to call a method on itself. It's possible for you to have overridden that method in a way that depends on that `let` var; if you were to call `super.init` before that var was initialized, you'd be in trouble. This is completely consistent with having to fully initialize `self` before calling a function/method on it — you have no idea what it might do, and it could depend on you being fully initialized.

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of undefined behavior? In asking the compiler to not check for "making sense", you're asking for an executable with undefined behavior. That said, Swift does provide an sort of "well-defined undefined behavior" that will let you get around some of the initialization rules: implicitly unwrapped optional properties. However, you should not get used to using them in production code. They are a workaround for very specific circumstances, not a way to force incomplete code through the compiler.

Comment: An interpreted language like Python or Ruby would give you the flexibility and lack of static analysis that you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Compiler errors are errors and not warnings for a reason: they are unrecoverable issues with your source code.

There are a few categories of errors which a program might have which may or may not be caught at different levels of the compiler:

1. **Syntax errors:** these are errors in your source code which make it an invalid program. It's not possible to ask the compiler to keep compiling a program past a syntax error because the code itself is not valid. You cannot, for instance, expect to have the compiler compile `?123?5445?,asdf,34124:::::!22` into a Swift program because it's just not Swift code.
2. **Semantic errors:** these are errors in which the code you've written is valid Swift, but may not make sense semantically. For instance, `func foo(_: String) {}; foo(5)` has a semantic error: you're passing an `Int` to a function expecting a `String`. Past semantic validation, the compiler needs to decide what intermediate language code to generate for a given expression; what code does it generate for `foo(5)`? It's possible to smash registers and stack state to pass any value in to anywhere, but this does explicitly against everything Swift stands for.

   - There are potential subcategories here, too. The above is a type mismatch error; the `super.init` error that you mention above is an enforcement of the rules of the language (all instance variables *must* be initialized before passing `self` into a function or calling a method on `self`).
3. **Logic errors:** these are errors which generally can't be caught by the compiler (off-by-one errors, incorrect multithreading code, etc.). Static analyzers might be able to help here, but these are generally runtime errors.

@JoshCaswell mentions undefined behavior above in a comment — some of the semantics of Swift are rules enforced in the attempt to excise undefined behavior from the language (like the initializer rules above). There is no "unsafe" mode which allows you to turn these rules off to say to Swift "I don't care about the semantics of these rules" because they're the code of what makes Swift the language that it is.

I can't think of any compiler that *does* allow you to keep compiling past a hard error. Even C and C++, which are bastions of undefined behavior, do not allow this, because compiling past an error introduces undefined behavior into the *compiler*; once you try to codegen an invalid AST, anything can go. You can get programs which are self-inconsistent or which make no sense. Much like assuming a false statement to be true allows you to prove *anything*, if you take invalid code and allow it to compile, the resulting program can do any number of completely nonsensical things.